# Standard for geospatial CSV with either lat/lon or region encoding

Tags: geocoding, csv, standards, interoperability, region

I'm tasked with finding a standard for data providers to publish data that is linked to either points (lat/lons), postcodes, or local government areas (Australian term for councils). The data will be published to an Open Data portal, and our tool will pull appropriately tagged datasets from there.

Is there any standard that I can base this off? I'm imagining something like:

---

Each row must contain one or more of:

- `lat` AND `lon` columns;
- `postcode` column (4 digits);
- `lga` column (string, not sure what the ids are)

---

That is, if they provide a postcode ("zipcode"), the rest of the row implicitly applies to the area bounded by that postcode. (Implementing this is easy.)

Any recommendations would be very welcome, even if it's just renaming the columns `au:lga` or something.

EDIT

Work in progress, fleshing out the above: https://github.com/NICTA/nationalmap/wiki/Aus-Geo-CSV-standard-(proposed)

Comment: If the location column is an integer (4 digits) it's a postcode, if it's a double then it's a lat (or lon) otherwise it's got to be an LGA.. is that right? Coming up with standards is never easy, there's always so many (justified) exceptions to the rule. Would LAT/LON be constrained to WGS84 (GDA94)? Otherwise there's bound to be entries in each MGA (or AMG) zone and Lamberts (SA, Vic and NSW are frequently used) and deciding what they are can be frustrating from just the numbers.

Comment: I'm proposing to explicitly label the columns `lat`/`lon` or `postcode` - not guessing by contents. Can you elaborate on the MGA/Lamberts problem? Does saying "EPSG:4326" make it go away? :)

Comment: Projected coordinates are definitely forbidden, if that's what you mean. (And yes, currently some datasets are in UTM etc, and yes, they're a pain.)

Comment: Lamberts projections are used for areas larger than one UTM zone, for example SA_Lamberts (EPSG:3107) to map all of South Australia with some reasonable distance/area instead of using zone 52, 53 and 54. If all you have is a table I don't know how you would specify a SRID/EPSG code, unless it's in the field name... a big step is (like KML) specifying that **all** coordinates *must* be EPSG:4326, that puts the onus on the providers to ensure compliance..

Comment: Yeah, my intention is very much requiring EPSG:4326 for all. The great majority of CSVs seem to use that anyway.